# Куда девается оперативная память?

Tags: windows, память, администрирование, производительность, ос

Друзья, такой вопрос: на борту 8 гигов оперативы. Когда только стартовал систему и открыл диспетчер задач -- тот показывает, что из 8 занято 4.3. При этом никакой софт я не запускал, тот же диспетчер задач показывает, что моя учётка хавает только 350 метров. Стоит десятка. Неужели ось съедает 4 гигабайта просто для себя?
Кто поумнее -- просветите, пожалуйста) Буду очень благодарен, друзья
Спасибо большое всем кто откликнется!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если кратко, то да) В системе запускается огромная куча служб.

Comment: Винда может заранее грузить в память часто используемые приложения.

Comment: Ну по крайней мере 2.3Г написано кеш. Эта память может быть освобождена, если понадобится. Но пока есть резервы там расположен кеш прочитанного с диска, для ускорения доступа

Comment: то есть вот эта кэшированная память (2.3Г) входит в ту, которая выделена (на скрине - 4.9Г) ?

Comment: Рекомендую к изучению эту презентацию: [Mysteries of Memory Management Revealed,with Mark Russinovich (Part 1 of 2)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TrFEgHr72Yg). Вот ещё: [Pushing the Limits of Windows: Physical Memory](https://web.archive.org/web/20100330012524/http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/archive/2008/07/21/3092070.aspx)